# Extracting most general type from multiple constructors

Tags: haskell

In the code below, I think the idea of the function `f` is reasonable, sure, we don't know the exact type of the first element of `D`, but we do know it is `T a` for some `a`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

data T a

data D where
  D1 :: T a -> D
  D2 :: T Bool -> D

f :: D -> (forall a. T a)
f (D1 x) = x
f (D2 x) = x

main = return ()
```

However, GHC throws the following error:

```
GADTTypes.hs:11:12: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘a1’ with ‘a’
      ‘a1’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        a pattern with constructor: D1 :: forall a. T a -> D,
        in an equation for ‘f’
        at GADTTypes.hs:11:4
      ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          f :: forall a. D -> T a
        at GADTTypes.hs:11:1
      Expected type: T a
        Actual type: T a1
    • In the expression: x
      In an equation for ‘f’: f (D1 x) = x
    • Relevant bindings include x :: T a1 (bound at GADTTypes.hs:11:7)
GADTTypes.hs:12:12: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘a’ with ‘Bool’
      ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          f :: forall a. D -> T a
        at GADTTypes.hs:11:1
      Expected type: T a
        Actual type: T Bool
    • In the expression: x
      In an equation for ‘f’: f (D2 x) = x
```

Just wondering whether what I'm trying to achieve is possible and how to fix my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haskell does not have `exists a. T a`, which is what you need, but you can declare your own type for that.

```
data T a

data D where
  D1 :: T a -> D
  D2 :: T Bool -> D

data ExT where
  ExT :: T a -> ExT

f :: D -> ExT
f (D1 x) = ExT x
f (D2 x) = ExT x
```

Then, if you have

```
g :: T a -> ...
```

and you want to compose `g (f x)` you need to use instead

```
case f x of
   ExT y -> g y
```

Note that the apparently equivalent following code will *not* type check, instead (because there is no `exists` type).

```
g (case f x of
     ExT y -> y)
```

You can craft your own helper, if you wish, for that:

```
help :: (forall a. T a -> b) -> ExT -> b
help h (ExT x) = h x

-- example
foo x = help g (f x)
```

This would keep the syntax closer to the plain `g (f x)`.

Answer (score 2):

Your signature claims that you return a `T a` for all `a`s I can think of. But if I pass you a `D2` and ask for a `T Int` you'll be unable to provide it, so your signature is lying ;)

I think you are misinterpreting `forall` as `exists` here. Existential types can be implemented through Universal types (forall) though, as shown in the [Haskell Wiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/Existential_type#Existentials_in_terms_of_.22forall.22).

Comment: So if I've got a function `g :: T a -> ...`, is there anyway to define `f` so that `g (f x)` compiles?

Comment: @Clinton Not with that exact syntax, no. That would require `f :: ... -> exists a. T a` which is not present in Haskell.